# Where can I find details about databricks cluster node types?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

In databricks we may select different node types. Where can I find details about these nodes?
For example:

Memory optimized: Standard_E4d_v4 - the only visible description says: 32GB RAM, 4 Cores

Storage optimized: Standard_L4s - the only visible description says: 32GB RAM, 4 Cores

So, in this case, based on the description I may assume they are the same, but for sure there are some differences. What differences? Where can I find details?

Comment: I have always assumed that the Cluster Node Types are internally VMs whose configuration and details we can compare. Maybe the below link might be useful ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes

Comment: The node types are very similar to VMs, so probably you are right. Thank you!

Comment: hopeman if issue resolved with @rainingdistros comment then post it as answer to help other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good answer from the comment above from [rainingdistros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13280838/rainingdistros).

The databricks cluster -> Azure VM, so if you want to know more details, check the configuration of the virtual machine.